# Mechanism of addition of H-X to alkynes

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Vinylic carbocation is unstable as the carbocation is bonded to a $\mathrm{sp^2}$ carbon that has high electron density, and pulls the electrons from the carbocation, which is already electron-deficient (empty $\mathrm{p}$ orbital)

However, the mechanism for the addition of $\ce{H-X (X = Cl/Br/I)}$ to alkynes involves the formation of vinylic carbocation, which to me, should not be plausible due to extremely high activation energy (the cation is very unstable).

Is the mechanism wrong or my concept on the stability of vinylic cation is wrong?
[image: Proposed mechanism of H-X addition to alkyne]

Comment: If I'm not wrong, Carey & Sundberg's *Advanced Organic Chemistry* has a section on these reactions and the available information regarding their mechanisms (and associated literature references). My suspicion is that it need not necessarily follow the "standard" mechanism that is taught for alkenes. I don't have the time to read and summarise it now, but it may be worth looking in there.

Comment: If you look at the acid catalysed hydration of alkynes the intermediate is indeed a vinylic carbocation. See here for details  https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2013/05/14/hydroboration-and-oxymercuration-of-alkynes/

Comment: The exact same reaction is explained here https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2013/05/24/alkyne-reaction-patterns-the-carbocation-pathway/

Comment: *"In general, alkynes are somewhat less reactive than alkenes toward many electrophiles. A major reason for this [...] is the substantially higher energy of the vinyl cation intermediate [...]"* (Carey/Sundberg A, 5ed, p 539) They go on to say that addition can occur either via the cation like in alkenes, or in a termolecular fashion which doesn't involve a discrete vinyl cation intermediate - the proportion seems to depend on substitution pattern - although in the link @Safdar posted there is an argument that vinyl cations are very rarely true intermediates

Comment: https://youtu.be/d7qdeCYq3UY?t=2340, in this lecture, around 39:40, the lecturer says vinyl cation can ONLY be formed with the addition of alkyne. However, according to Hammond's postulate, the activation energy of this step should be extremely high that the reaction cannot proceed, which I think @Safdar's post is right. So may I ask for the rate law of this reaction?

Comment: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jo01292a023 The preview of this article talks about the dependance of rate law on atmost three different constants depending on reaction conditions

Comment: However that is for bromination, for addition of Hydrogen chloride, according to *The Chemistry of the Carbon-Carbon Triple Bond, Part 1*, Chap 8, p 281. It is stated that It would be second order for addition of H-Cl to acetylene.. I do not have access to the book itself so I can't say more. this was using google search in books to find out. Someone else who could access would be able to tell you more

Comment: @234ff That is not the correct application of the Hammond postulate. It is perfectly reasonable to argue that a transition state is higher in energy than the intermediate it leads to without any reference to the Hammond postulate.